# RGraph hide line plus labels with a click on key element

Tags: javascript, canvas, rgraph

So, I have a graph like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to hide the lines plus the labels with it when I click the key referring that line.

I found [this](https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/docs/keys-in-charts.html#active-key-elements) on the docs and I tried doing this:

```
$(line.canvas).on('click', function (e) //line is the name of the graph of both green and red lines
        {
            var key = RGraph.Registry.get('key-element');
            console.log(key);

            if (key) {
                console.log("true");
            }
        });
```

I found this to be pointless due the fact when I click on the keys they return weird outputs, either `null` or other key different from the one I want.

What I also found on [RGraph Line API](https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/docs/line.html#methods) is that `obj.hide([index])` only sets the color to `rgba(0,0,0,0)`, which does not hide the `labelsAbove` property.

How can I fix this and make a proper hide of the lines when I click on the key?

Comment: I was about to suggest the .hide() function until you mentioned the labelsAbove not being hidden too. I'll have to fix this for v5.1

Comment: @Richard cool then :p what about the key problem?

Comment: Key problem? To hide the line You could indeed use the hide() method in conjunction with an interactive key event ( beforeinteractivekey or afterinteractivekey ) as it is at the moment though you'll still get the labelsAbove. In the event after you hide the relevant line in theory you could alter the labelsAbove labels so the relevant lines labelsAbove labels are blank - so they wouldn't show). You'd need to use labelsAboveSpecific I think. It wouldn't be insignificant.

Comment: I'm releasing a new version tomorrow so when I've done with that I can work on having the labelsAbove labels not visible when the relevant line isn't.

Comment: Thanks @Richard! I'll try that way then :)

Comment: @Richard The events(beforeinteractivekey or afterinteractivekey) doesn't have the required [behaviour](https://media.giphy.com/media/ZZOIPqtI5t26kghGYV/giphy.gif). When page is refreshed it triggers the event, clicking on the interactive keys doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this demo hides/shows the line but the labelsAbove labels are still there. So I'll have to look at this for the next beta.

Here's the code:

```
function createandcall(rackname, racknameid, stb) {
    $('#maintable').append('<table class="table"><tbody><tr style="text-align:center"><td><h2>' + rackname + '</h2><table class="table"><tbody style="text-align:left"><tr id="STBL"></tr><tr id="STBL1"></tr><tr id="STBL2"></tr><tr id="STBL3"></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>');
    for (i = 1; i < stb + 1; i++) {
        createtable(i);
        callstb(rackname, racknameid, i);
    }
    return;
}

function callstb(rackname, racknameid, i) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'text',
        url: "http://localhost:3000/index/" + rackname + ' ' + racknameid + ' ' + i,
        success: function (data) {
            response = '\#stb' + i;
            idtd = '\#tdstb' + i;
            $(response).html(data.replace(/\[32m/gi, '').replace(/\[0\;33m/gi, '').replace(/\[0m/gi, '').replace(/\[33m/gi, '').replace(/\[37m/gi, '').replace(/\[31m/gi, ''));
            pre = $(response).html().toString();

        },
        error: function (error) {
            $("#error").html('Error trying to get the STBs report');
            $("#error").show();
        }
    })
}
```

server.js:

```
app.get('/index/*', (req, res) => {
    parsedparam = req.params[0].split(" ")
    rackname = parsedparam[0]
    racknameid = parsedparam[1]
    stb = parseInt(parsedparam[2])
    verifystbs(rackname, racknameid, stb, res);
});

function openconnection() {
    con.connect(() => { console.log("RackChecker connected with database!") });
}

function closeconnection() {
    con.end(() => { console.log("Connection Closed") });
}

function verifystbs(rackname, racknameid, stb, res) {
    openconnection();
    con.query("SELECT (SELECT UCASE(name) FROM models WHERE s.model = id) as Model,\
        (SELECT UCASE(name) FROM manufacturers WHERE s.manufacturer = id) as Branch,\
        (SELECT UCASE(name) FROM racks WHERE s.rack = id) as Rack,\
        s.name as Stb,\
        x.pr as Jira, \
        x.reason as Reason,\
        x.requestor AS Stress_Request,\
        x.version as Version\
        FROM \
        stbs s \
        LEFT JOIN \
        stressrun x \
        ON (s.active = 1 && s.rack = (SELECT id FROM racks WHERE name = '"+ racknameid + "')) \
        WHERE x.id = (SELECT max(id) FROM stressrun y WHERE y.stb_id = s.id) and s.name like ('STB_%"+ stb + "')\
        and x.reason in ('failed','other','new build') ORDER BY s.name;", (err, result) => {
        console.log(result)
        if (!Array.isArray(result) || !result.length) {
            callnewstb = shell.exec('./shellscript/callnewstb.sh ' + rackname + ' ' + stb, { async: true });
            callnewstb.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                res.send(data);
            });
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                parsestbnumber = result[i].Stb.split("_");
                stbnumber = parseInt(parsestbnumber[1]);
                stbnumber = stbnumber * 1;
                if (stb == stbnumber) {
                    res.send("Stress Test is not running on <b>" + result[i].Stb + "</b><br>Reason: <b>" + result[i].Reason + "</b><br>Jira Ticket: <b><a href='https://link.jira.com/browse/" + result[i].Jira + "'>" + result[i].Jira + "</a></b><br>Build Version: <b>" + result[i].Version)
                    break
                }
                else {
                    callnewstb = shell.exec('./shellscript/callnewstb.sh ' + rackname + ' ' + stb, { async: true });
                    callnewstb.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                        res.send(data);
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    });
    closeconnection();
}
```

Comment: I'll add the the hiding of the labelsAbove so that when a line is hidden the labels go too.

Comment: Yeah, that would be great.

Comment: Well, with that library it's throwing [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYwmf.png) while the 5.01 line chart library it's working fine. Do you want me to send a snippet of my code?

Comment: [Nope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhSfv.png) :p the labels don't appear and when i click on one of the keys it throws those 2 errors in the red circle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197391/discussion-between-caldeirag-and-richard).